# How to create statically typed python class with same typed member

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I am from java background, learning python. I am trying to create a python class (with static typing), containing a member of same class.

**mynode.py**

```
class MyNode():
    def __init__(self, id: str=None, child_node: MyNode=None):
        self._id = id
        self._child_node = child_node
```

**main.py**

```
import mynode

def main():
    n1 = MyNode('child1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But the following errors are occurring while executing. How can this be resolved ?

```
...\py-tests>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mynode
  File "...\py-tests\mynode.py", line 1, in <module>
    class MyNode():
  File "...\py-tests\mynode.py", line 2, in MyNode
    def __init__(self, id: str=None, child_node: MyNode=None):
NameError: name 'MyNode' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time `__init__` is being defined, the class itself isn't yet defined, let alone bound to a name. Use a [forward reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/?utm_source=recordnotfound.com#forward-references) instead, consisting of a string literal.

```
class MyNode:
    def __init__(self, id: str = None, child_node: 'MyNode' = None):
```